# What would happen if a large body of liquid were to fall from space?

Tags: atmospheric-science

Much like how meteors enter our atmosphere all the time, what would happen if a large body of a liquid were to enter our atmosphere, and make it to the ground? If a meteor were to hit the ground, it could be catastrophic. But what if it wasn't a solid? Would the effects be the same?

Comment: Such a body cannot exist in the vacuum of space.

Answer (score 2):

First of all, the most of the liquid will get vaporised continuously on its way down, due to the heat produced by compressing the air in front of it. Assuming some of it makes through the burning flight, it will crash at supersonic speeds onto the earth. There will be slight tremors around for some distance. On touching the ground, there will be a tremendous buildup of pressure inside the liquid body.Assuming that the ground is pretty much made of rock solid stuff(not muddy or sandy), the tremendous pressure built up inside the drop will cause the liquid drop to break, forcing water jets to travel along the ground at supersonic speeds, destroying almost everything in its path for a large region.

Comment: So, not a big difference from a solid meteor, if enough mass makes it through the atmosphere. Kinetic energy will be about the same

Comment: Well at such speeds, even liquid behaves effectively as a solid. However, a solid meteorite will dig a crater even in the rock bed, the the liquid wont.

Comment: Makes sense, it'll splatter more, still probably almost the same deadliness (not sure if that's a word), thanks.